# Hypothetical model of particle collision

Tags: particle-physics, collision

I am thinking that suppose we have a sample of particles in a box, all of them has mass 1. Also let us put the constraint on the particle collision such that at each time step only two particles can collide with each other at random. Furthermore, let us assume that after collision nothing annihilates. Instead a new particle is being made so if we have $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$ we take two of them at random say $m_1$ and $m_3$ now we have $m_4$ which has mass 2 as $m_1+m_3$.

Suppose we look at this scenario for $M$ number of distinct particle and over time $T$. Is it possible to find the distribution of $m_1, m_2$, ..., $m_n$? also is it possible to calculate the distribution of new made particle such as $m_n+m$?

The real particle physics set up is quite different in collision events obviously. This is more of a thought experiment, I think one can do keep track of events via an algorithm but I was wondering if one can formulate it as a general case?

Comment: You say nothing is annihilated, so does that mean that after the collision that $m_1$ and $m_3$ still exist as well as the new $m_4$?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes indeed.

Comment: OK. That's not a very physical scenario then, since it doesn't conserve energy, so it's probably not that interesting to real physicists. There might be a simple formula to describe the typical evolution of your system, but if so, it's not obvious to me. I suggest that you write a program to do a simple simulation and see what patterns occur.